# How to return an object in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a function which will return various form objects. eg Label. However I am not able to achieve the same.

My code looks like this:

```
function add_label([String]$label_text, [Int]$label_location_x, [Int]$label_location_y, [Int]$lable_size) {
    $label              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.AutoSize     = $true
    $label.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($label_location_x,$label_location_y)
    $label.Size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($lable_size,20)
    $label.Text         = $label_text

    $label
}
$label_product = add_label("Product: ", $label_product_location, 20, $LableSize)
$GroupBoxSetting.Controls.Add($label_product)
```

It does not throw any error, however the label is not displayed. Instead "`product: 30 20 50`" is displayed in the GUI instead of `$groupBoxSetting` Text.

I was wondering, is there any way to create a function, which returns the Forms object, so that we do not have to write the same code block again and again for each Forms object.

Comment: You're calling your function incorrectly, powershell doesn't use the `function(x, y, z)` syntax. Instead it should look like this: `add_label -label_text "Product: " -label_location_x $label_product_location -label_location_y 20 -lable_size $LableSize`

Comment: For cleaner syntax try using splatting like this:
`$params = @{

   'label_text'='hello';
   'label_location_x'=50;
   'label_location_y'=50;
   'lable_size'=10;

}`

`add_label @params`

May not look clean in the comments because I don't know how to post multi-line code comments. You can find out more about splatting [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling your function incorrectly, powershell doesn't use the brackets around the parameters.

Doing this is causing everything inside the brackets to be sent as a single object to the first parameter.

You can use named parameters, which is easy to tell what is being passed to which param:

```
add_label -label_text "Product: " -label_location_x $label_product_location -label_location_y 20 -lable_size $LableSize
```

Or positional parameters, which is less to type, but harder to interpret if you don't know the function params already:

```
add_label "Product: " $label_product_location 20 $LableSize
```

See [about_parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters) for more info on this.